# WebSphere with SSO Authentication leading to blank page using CAS Server

Tags: proxy, certificate, websphere, single-sign-on, cas

I am using Websphere 6.1 with SSO authentication using CAS Server,
When I try to access my website I get a blank page with this error in my websphere server1 log :

> org.jasig.cas.client.proxy.ProxyGrantingTicketStorageImpl retrieve No Proxy Ticket found for [].

Any suggestion ?

Thank you for your help !

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by SSL issues, my website was in HTTP not in HTTPS and cookies was enabled only for HTTPS : after a user logs into the server, the server generates an LTPA token, which is an encrypted hash that contains authenticated user information. The token is signed by a private key that is shared among all the servers that want to decode it. The token is usually **in cookie form for HTTP services**. By sending the token as a cookie, the need for subsequent user interaction is avoided.

So beaucause cookies were enabled only for HTTPS connections in both server and Application, LTPA token is expired for the reason that he is not stored in a cookie.

All you have to do is uncheking "enable cookies for HTTPS only" for both server and application by accessing managing session in websphere console, save changes and reboot WAS and the application.

The error behind in websphere systemout.log was as mentionned below :
**SECJ0371W**: Validation of the LTPA token failed because the token expired with the following info: Token expiration Date: Fri Mar 15 22:16:00 UTC 2019, current Date: Fri Mar 15 22:18:35 UTC 2019.

Best regards.